# Permanent NULL-body error in HTTP request by using HTTP module

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm using the last master release of NodeMCU on a WeMos D1 mini. I'm trying to debug a simple script to send data from the sensors to the server
using the HTTP-post request.

```
-- BME280 Setup
sda, scl = 3, 4
sleep_time = 9000000
i2c.setup(0, sda, scl, i2c.SLOW) -- call i2c.setup() only once
bme280.setup()
-- BME280 Read
--T, P, H = bme280.read()


-- Analog read
adc.force_init_mode(adc.INIT_ADC)
--I = adc.read(0)

-- Send data to Orange Pi
--payload = {"sensor": "outdoor", "t": T/100, "p": P/1000, "h": H/1000, "l": I} 

http.post("http://orangepipc2.local/cgi-bin/data_coll.py", 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n', 'sensor=test&t=23&p=10001&h=33&l=500',
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
      print("Sent to the web OK")
    end
  end) 


-- Deep Sleep
--node.dsleep(sleep_time)
```

And I'm constantly getting an error of "*HTTP client: Body shouldn't be NULL*". Even when using an example from the documentation.

I looked through the source code of the module and I was confused by a piece of code:

```c
if (NULL == body) {
      /* Find missing body */
      HTTPCLIENT_ERR("Body shouldn't be NULL");
      /* To avoid NULL body */
      body = "";
} else {
      /* Skip CR & LF */
      body = body + 4;
}
```

The if for some reason, is always true. Is there a difference in the order of the arguments in the comparison operation? Or an error where in another place?

Comment: is there any more feedback you need?

Answer (score 2):

Acording to [the documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/http/#httppost), the body is the third parameter.

> ## Syntax
>
> `http.post(url, headers, body, callback)`

You need to add the second parameter (headers) as `nil`:

```
http.post("http://orangepipc2.local/cgi-bin/data_coll.py", nil, 'sensor=test&t=23&p=10001&h=33&l=500',
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
      print("Sent to the web OK")
    end
  end)
```

Comment: Yes I know.
My apologize.
In the process of experimentation, the code changed and I did not notice that I had placed the wrong version. corrected.
However, as I said above, it still does not work. even on an example from the documentation.

Comment: Also note that if the error: "HTTP client: Body should not be NULL", nevertheless the request is sent, but with an empty body, in fact it can be seen from the source code. and if the number of parameters is incorrect, the query is simply not executed. without error messages.

Comment: "it still does not work. even on an example from the documentation." - nope, ain't true. The example in the docs works just fine with the current version from the master branch. I just tried _with_ (i.e. as-is) and _without_ the extra headers.